# Create a folder inside other folders using bash

Tags: bash

I have a long list of folders that are siblings to each other, they all start with "0" <del>and are numerically named (001, 002, 003...)</del> but names are not only numerical and are not correlative (for example I have 0010_foo, 0032_bar, 0150_baz, etc).
I need to create a new folder (js) inside each of the folders on my list. I'd like to do it recursively using the command line.

I've tried:

```
$ cd path/to/my/root/folder
$ find 0* -type d -exec mkdir js {} \;
```

But I get an error for each attempt: "mkdir: js: file exists". No need to say there's no directory named js inside my folders but they are files with .js extension.

Where is the error in my command and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Would this work for you? `for i in 0*/; do mkdir "$i"js; done`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've tested it quickly and seems to be working fine. I like the solution, you might want to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of your directory structure after your edit, but give this a whirl:

```
cd /path/to/my/root/folder
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type d -exec mkdir -p {}/js \;
```

Seems to work ok:

```
$ cd /path/to/my/root/folder
$ tree
.
├── 001
│   └── js
└── 002
$ find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type d -exec mkdir -p {}/js \;
.
├── 001
│   └── js
└── 002
    └── js
```

What this `find` does: In the current directory (`.`), it finds sub-directories (`-type d`) -- except the current directory itself (`! -path .`) and any sub-sub-directories (`-maxdepth 1`).  In those found directories, it creates the desired sub-directory (`-exec ...`).  The `mkdir -p` part creates the directory and silences any errors about parents not existing. find replaces the `{}` part with the actual directory it found.

Comment: I've tried in a test folder and seems to work fine. Could you explain a bit what is the command doing? short explanation, so the answer is more complete

Comment: Note that this might not work with all versions of `find`: `-maxdepth` and `-path` are not specified by POSIX, and POSIX clearly states that _If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change._ There are no problems with GNU `find`, though.

Comment: @chepner I've got POSIX deja vu.

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir js {}` tries to create two directories; you want `mkdir {}/js`.

To prevent `find` from repeatedly finding your new directory, ignore any directory named `js`.

```
find 0* ! -path '*/js' -type d -exec mkdir {}/js \;
```

Comment: running with `mkdir {}/js` entered a wild loop where multiple nested "js" folders where created... could you elaborate your answer a bit so I can see where the problem is?

Comment: Oh, `find` is finding the new directory on each pass. I think it's an easy fix.

Comment: I guess that you can avoid the `! -path js` predicate (and hence not rely on `-path` which is not really portable) and use `-depth` instead: `find -depth -name '0*' -type d -exec mkdir {}/js \;` (noting that `{}/js` might not work with all versions of `find`).

Comment: still looping crazily... is it actually working for you?

Comment: How is `-path` not portable? It's in the POSIX spec.

Comment: @ithil Try my update; I don't have time to test it now unfortunately.

Comment: It's not in the (rather old now) issue #6, but in issue #7. `-depth`, on the other hand, is supported in older versions, and seems to really solve the problem (problem occurs because of breadth first, and `-depth` switches to depth first).

Answer (score 2):

(Why your `find` command doesn't work is already explained in bishop's (now deleted) answer — I'm only giving an alternative to `find`).

You can replace `find` by a shell `for` loop as so:

```
for i in 0*/; do mkdir "$i"js; done
```

Comment: there's still your explanation of problems `find` might have in @bishop current answer, maybe you could add it here