# Bash script to recursively traverse every subdirectory and create a new directory on every level

Tags: bash, directory, traversal

The title says it all. I am trying to write a bash script to recursively traverse every subdirectory give a starting directory as $1 and create a directory inside that folder. So give the starting directory structure

starting_directory

- dir_1
- dir_2

  - dir 3

The new structure would be

starting_directory

- dir_1

  - new_dir
- dir_2

  - dir_3

    - new_dir
  - new_dir
- new_dir

I'm very new to bash (like this afternoon new) so I could use some help.

Comment: Start with `find "$1" -type d`

Comment: Be sure to test that solutions don't recurse on your `new_dir`, ending up with `dir_1->new_dir->new_dir->new_dir->new_dir->.......` Search here for answers with the `cd` command, the `mkdir` cmd, and tests with `if [[ -d "$current_dir" ]] ; then do_it_again ; fi`. The `find` suggestion above is even better. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a folder inside other folders using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631610/create-a-folder-inside-other-folders-using-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
find $1 -type d -a -not -name new_dir -print0 | xargs -0 -i@ mkdir -p @/new_dir
```

The `find` recursively descends a file or directory hierarchy. `-type d` means only look at directories. `-a -not -name new_dir` means exclude directories already named `new_dir` (avoiding a possible infinite loop) ("and not name"). `-print0` means print it out with a terminating null (this correctly handles directories with spaces in them). Pipe this (`|`) to the program `xargs`, which passes every line in standard input to the given command. `-0` matches with the `-print0` of the find to separate filenames by nuls. `-i@` means replace `@` in the command with the received filename. `mkdir` of course makes the directory; `-p` avoids any potential ordering problems by forcing intervening directories to be created if they don't exist, and avoids complaining if the directory already exists. `@/new_dir` uses the input to create the new directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive globbing to get just the subdirectories in a directory tree and make new directories in them:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Make sure recursive globs are enabled
shopt -s globstar

# Cd to the target root directory and populate its subdirs
cd "$1"
for dir in **/; do
    mkdir "$dir/new_dir"
done

# Finally add one in the root of the tree
mkdir new_dir
```